# Identify this bird

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

I have attached below the image of a bird that I see everyday from my balcony. Since I do not have a good camera, I searched the image of the bird on Google. It feeds on insects. I live in Satna (Madhya Pradesh), India.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably seeing an Indian Roller (*Coracias benghalensis*).
[image]

Which is similar but not the same to the picture you posted; which is a  [racket-tailed roller](http://howardcheek.photoshelter.com/image/I00000pFELDDsKVk) (*Coracias spatulatus*) a similar species of Roller  found in Africa.

However in India do occur other 2 species of Roller, the European Roller and the Dollarbird. You can check pictures of this other 2 species online and compare them with the bird you see every day.

Comment: Your guess is that the bird in question is an Indian Roller. However, you also said that there are two species of rollers found in India. Therefore, what I want to ask you is whether the Indian Roller is different from the European Roller or the Dollarbird?

Comment: Yes they are different as you can quickly see from a rapid google research. I guessed based on the most common species given in your area and asked you to check.